# Using JAVA GiLab API, how I can identify branch and files are related to specific hash

Tags: java, git, gitlab

I am using the JAVA GitLabAPI (https://github.com/timols/java-gitlab-api), and I want to identify which modified files and branch are related to an specific hash code. I took a look on the Internet and found the method getCommitDiffs. Then implemented the following code:

```
GitlabAPI api = GitlabAPI.connect(host, key, token);

List<GitlabCommitDiff> diffs = api.getCommitDiffs(projectId, hash);
```

However, I did not understand what's the ProjectId. The id is already defined by the GitLab website or I can choose it ?

Answer (score 0):

The project ID is created during the creation using the GUI or API. 
It is fixed and cannot be changed.

You can retrieve the IDs using the `Project`class. 
There you can read out every project or enclose the search using parameters.

GITLAB API:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects

PROJECT CLASS of `gitlab4j-api`:
https://github.com/gmessner/gitlab4j-api/blob/master/src/main/java/org/gitlab4j/api/ProjectApi.java